# Action of $S_4$ in $S_4/S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G = S_4$, $H = S_3$, $X = G/H$ be the set of right cosets of $H$, $x = (14)H$ and $G $ acts on $X$ by conjugation.  Compute $\mathscr{O} (x)$ and $G_x$ (the stabilizer of $x$).

I've got a problem in this question. Clearly, $\mathscr{O}(x) = \{(14)H, (24)H, (34)H, H \}$and $G_x = 1$, however it leads to a contradiction, since $|G_x| = |G|/|\mathscr{O}(x) | = 24 / 4 = 6$. I really do not know what's wrong in my answer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I assume $H$ is permutations of $\{1, 2, 3\}$ and fixes $4$.

The subgroup $H$ is not normal in $G$, so the conjugation action of $G$ on itself does not descend to a conjugation action of $G$ on $G/H$.  For example if we conjugate $H$ by $(1 \ 4)$ we get the copy of $S_3 \subseteq S_4$ given by permutations of $\{2, 3, 4\}$.  But this subgroup is not a right coset of $H$.

If you want an action of $G$ on $G/H$ use left multiplication.  Or, if you want your action to be conjugation you could act on the set of subgroups, or even the set of subsets of $G$.

Comment: The action is given by $h .(gH) = h^{-1}ghH$.

Comment: If $g \in H$ then $gH = 1H$.  For the action to be well defined you would then need $hgh^{-1}H = h1h^{-1}H = 1H$, i.e., you would need $hgh^{-1} \in H$.  But this is not true for all $g \in H$ because $H$ is not normal.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity, but I'm considering just representatives of each coset, then such $gH$ (with $g \in H$) would not be in $X$, therefore I think it's well defined.

Comment: @user40276: If you want the action to be on elements then you are acting by conjugation on $G$, not on $G/H$.  The conjugation action on $G$ is perfectly well defined, the conjugation action on $G/H$ is only well defined when $H$ is normal.

Comment: Sorry for my insistence, but this is not exactly about what I want. This question was written in a list of exercises that I received as a homework. So I'm trying to understand what was intention of the person that created this question. That's why I suggested the action on a set of representatives of each coset and, in this case, $g \notin X$.

Comment: @user40276: If the action is on *cosets* of $H$ and not on elements then the action $h\cdot(gH) = (hgh^{-1})H$ is well defined if and only if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.  This is not true of the $H$ and $G$ you were given.  It's likely the professor that came up with these problems simply made a mistake.

Comment: Confirmed now, the question was mistyped in the list. The action was by translation and then this is easy to compute. Thanks for the patience.